# Numbers in dictionary

Tags: knowledge, english

Each number from 1 to 5,000 are written in formal english (e.g. two hundred eleven,one hundred thirty five etc.) and then listed in alphabetic order (as in dictionary, where spaces and hyphens are ignored)

What is the first odd number in the list?

Bonus: Tell the last prime no.

Comment: Do you have a preference on inclusion or omission of and? I.e. As between AmEn and BrEn. Where many Americans would write one hundred one, where others would always write one hundred and one.

Comment: I disagree that this is a dupe. The premise is the same, but this one uses a different number range, and therefore has a different answer. It's like the differences between the "Make X using A, B, C, and D" questions.

Comment: @mikeroger i gave an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it would be

> eight hundred eighty-five

as

> eight* is the digit which comes earliest in the alphabet of, eight hundred is before eighty (and eighteen is ineligible), and five is the odd digit which comes earliest.

EDIT: one could argue that

> eighteen hundred eighty-five

would be first, but that's not the "formal" way to write it.

Comment: Eight isn't odd

Comment: Yeah, I can't think of anything better, I think this is right...

Answer (score 2):

Building up from Sneftel his answer, (I don't have the rep to comment on his answer, so this will do.)

In British English,

> It would be Eight-hundred-and-eighty-five

As Sneftel stated,

> Eight* is the digit which comes earliest in the alphabet...
>  
>  You could use -and- between hundreds and tenths, but only in British English.

EDIT:

> My previous answer was Eight-hundred-and-five, but as @Untitpoi reminded me that I could use -and- even if there are tenths in the number, Eight-hundred-and-eighty-five would be better. (Which is the same number as Sneftel's answer.)

Comment: This handily shows why I don't like these "numbers in English" puzzles. In the USA you say "eight hundred five". Almost everywhere else says "eight hundred and five".

Comment: In the question it seems "and" is not allowed as the author has said _one hundred thirty five_ and not _one hundred **and** thirty five_